# How to find out the real dns server addresses when dnsmasq is installed

Tags: dnsmasq

In general, we can find out the DNS server addresses we are using by `cat /etc/resolve.conf`. However, after dnsmasq is installed, the DNS server address becomes `127.0.0.1` in the file `/etc/resolve.conf`. How can I find out the real DNS server addresses in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, recently I finally find out the way to see which DNS servers are using.

1. `cat /var/log/kern.log | grep nameserver` will show the DNS server configuration received by the NetworkManager.
2. `nmcli dev show <IF> | grep DNS` will also do that.
3. `cat /var/log/syslog | grep dnsmasq` will also tell you which upstream nameservers dnsmasq is using. This may be the most accurate way.
4. `cat /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf` also works for me.

Comment: The 4. doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 18.04, it does return dnsmasq's local IP 172.0.0.53. nmcli dev show | grep DNS does work well for me.